# CryptoJS encrypt Go decrypt

Tags: encryption, go, aes, cryptojs

I have the following Go code

```
ciphertext := "Zff9c+F3gZu/lsARvPhpMau50KUkMAie4j8MYfb12HMWhkLqZreTk8RPbtRB7RDG3QFw7Y0FXJsCq/EBEAz//XoeSZmqZXoyq2Cx8ZV+/Rw="
decodedText, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(ciphertext)
decodedIv, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("u9CV7oR2w+IIk8R0hppxaw==")
newCipher, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte("~NB8CcOL#J!H?|Yr"))
cfbdec := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(newCipher, decodedIv)
cfbdec.CryptBlocks(decodedText, decodedText)
data, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(decodedText))
println(string(data))
```

The output is `{"data":{"value":300}, "SEQN":700 , "msg":"IT WORKS!!"`

It's encrypted with the following CryptoJS

```
function encrypt(message, key) {
  let keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(parseToHex(key))
  let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
  let wordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message);
  let base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(wordArray);
  let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(base64, keyHex, { iv: iv });
  return {
    cipher: encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64),
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(iv),
    length: base64.length,
    size: encrypted.ciphertext.sigBytes,
  }
}
```

And can be decrypted with

```
function decrypt(message, key, iv) {
  let ivEX = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(decodeToHex(iv));
  let keyEX = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(parseToHex(key));
  let bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(message, keyEX , { iv: ivEX});
  let plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  return decodeToString(decodeToString(plaintext));
}
```

The output is `{"data":{"value":300}, "SEQN":700 , "msg":"IT WORKS!!" }` - this is the correct output

Why Go has different output?

Comment: Is it just missing the end `}` or am I not seeing something?

Comment: space and }, 2 characters

Comment: The variable names `decryptedText` and `decryptedIV` are not accurate and confusing, they are the decoded Base64 and actually the encrypted data and IV. It is also easier to debug if the decryption is no into the same buffer as the encrypted data.

Comment: @zaph correct, edited. However I was not able to use another buffer

Comment: @IvayloIvanov Hello, I have currently been working on encryption and I am in the same situation. I am encrypting the message in frontend using Cryptojs and decrypting it in Go. The code I have in Go decrypts the message but gives gibberish value in the end. I found your working solution and trying to replicate the same. Your code has a function called ParseHex(). Would you please share this function implementation or tell me what exactly the function is doing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello @Neha I've tried to find the repository where I have the code.. I'm not sure if that's the one, but looking at it, it might. I've created a public gist. Hope that helps https://gist.github.com/ivaylopivanov/a1e27e7e1e3cc2263d5fa536ab66016b

Comment: @IvayloIvanov thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your errors please. ALWAYS

`illegal base64 data at input byte 75`

https://play.golang.org/p/dRLIT51u4I

More specifically, the value at byte 75 is `5`, which is out of the range of characters available to base64. In ascii, it is the ENQ (enquiry) character. As to why this ends up in your final base64 string is beyond me.

EDIT: OK found the issue. For whatever reason, the base64 padding character `=` at the end is being decrypted as 5 consecutive bytes containing the value `5`. Here is a playground link that shows it fixed. https://play.golang.org/p/tf3OZ9XG1M

EDIT: As per matt's comments. I updated the fix function to simply remove all the PKCS7 block padding and use `RawStdEncoding` for the last base64 decode. This should now be a reasonable fix.

Comment: The `5` char is the PKCS7 block padding—oddly the Go crypto libs don’t include any padding code so you have to add padding when encrypting and remove padding when decrypting yourself. Another issue is that if the `=` characters are missing (which is the case in the example ciphertext) then there will be an error with the `StdEncoding` base64 decoder. This can be fixed by making sure the `=` characters are always included, or more robustly by using the `RawStdEncoding`: https://play.golang.org/p/-XLlPoMHDN

Comment: I tried `RawStdEncoding` and it still complained about the junk chars. I guess the best way to fix it is to remove all the `5`s and use `RawStdEncoding`. Thanks for the insight @matt

Comment: Yes, `RawStdEncoding` will work if the `=` chars are missing, but not if there are extra chars there such as the trailing padding bytes. (There are _two_ problems here—the missing `=` characters and the block padding not being stripped. It just happens that they both cause the same error (and confusingly they both involve “padding” of some sort)).

Comment: The [PKCS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) character isn’t necessarily `5`, it depends on how much padding is needed. It could be 1–16.

Comment: So if the last char is out of base64 range, then remove that many chars? That is a lot easier, unless the PKCS7 byte size is large enough to need 43 chars of padding XD. Edited for this.

Comment: Nearly—you _always_ remove padding. So just look at the last byte and remove that many bytes. (Ideally you should really also check that this number is less or equal to 16 (the block size), and that all the removed bytes have the same value)

Comment: I asked related question about the encryption http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115160/go-aes-encrypt-decrypt